# Pegar todas as informações de uma <tr>

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom dia.

Dentro de uma tag `<tr>` existem cerca de 15 tag's `<td>` (informações vindas do banco de dados) nem todas estão sendo exibidas. Cada `<tr>` possuí uma `<td>` com a opção de clicar e um modal abrir com todas as informações necessárias.

Como eu faço para pegar todas as informações que estão presentes nas `<td>` de cada `<tr>` especifica?

```
<?php $professoresListados = buscarProfessor($conexao);

    foreach($professoresListados as $professor)
    {
        echo "
            <tr>
                <td class='infoPhp' id='{$professor['idProfessor']}'>{$professor['idProfessor']}</td>
                <td><img src='../../../Accipiter/Imagens/Professor/noimage.jpg' class='imgTabela'></td>
                <td>{$professor['nomeProfessor']}</td>
                <td class='non759'>{$professor['emailProfessor']}</td>
                <td class='non759'>{$professor['cpfProfessor']}</td>
                <td style='cursor: pointer;' id='{$professor['idProfessor']}' class='atribSession' onclick='capturarId(this.id)'><i class='fa fa-sign-in' aria-hidden='true'></i></td>
            </tr>";
    }
?>
```

As `<td class='non759'>` não são exibidas para o usuário. Mas ao clicar na `<td>` de visualização um modal abre e todas as informações são encontradas la. Como pegar todos os dados de dentro da `<tr>` ?

Comment: Olá, você poderia adicionar essa parte do código, ajudaria ?

Comment: Ve ai se da uma melhorada no entendimento :)

Comment: $("tr").each(function(){ console.log($(this).children("td").text());});